# Jquery Slider: Display the stored value

Tags: jquery, slider

I use the following script to embed the jquery slider:

The slider shows me after saving the default-value "21". How can I set it so that it shows me the stored value from the input form?

```
 <script>
$(function() {
 $( "#slider" ).slider({
value:21,
        min: 16,
        max: 75,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#um_field_34_test" ).val( ui.value );
  }
});
$("#um_field_34_test").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="alter" value="75" id="um_field_34_test" class="um_field_34 um_input validate[custom[number]]" label_id="um_field_34_test_label">
```

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Did you try reading the docs for this widget?

Comment: Yes, but I dont understand where I have to put in

     var value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );